# Which FP language follows lambda calculus the closest?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Which FP language follows lambda calculus the closest in terms of its code looking, feeling, acting like lambda calculus abstractions?

Comment: I voted to close as this is subjective...

Comment: "I'd also like to hear opinions on whether this matters or not" That depends on your requirements of course, but I don't see why it would (matter) unless your goal is to learn the lambda calculus (in which case you probably should use a more direct implementation of the lambda calculus anyway instead of a "real" programming language).

Comment: @sepp2k: My dilemma is this: I hear how important lc is and how it is at the root of FP, but then I try to learn FP language x, y, z -- and they all seem to avoid direct comparisons with formal lc. This is troubling and confusing for a beginner.

Comment: @melwasul Just learn the language you want to learn. Lambda calculus played an important role in the creation of functional languages (in the sense that it inspired them), but there's really no why the closeness of a language to the LC should be a criterion for picking a programming language to learn.

Comment: I'm making my way through The Little Schemer and I'm also trying to translate the functions (e.g. p 132 insert-g) into lambda abstractions as I go along. I see the similarities and wonder if other FP languages can be translated into lc. But then what Don Stewart (and others) seem to say is FP languages leave basic lc behind when real-world tasks need doing, i.e., the whole Peano style of recursive math is not always desirable when you want to code a GUI interface, etc.

Comment: Peano style is not appropriate when you want hardware to execute your math efficiently. Think of the cpu as hardware acceleration for common lambda calculus functions.

Answer (score 6):

This might not be a real answer, it's more of a guess about what you actually want.

In general, there's very little in the lambda calculus -- you basically need (first-class) functions, function applications, and variables.  These days you'll have hard time finding a language that does *not* provide you with these things...  However, things can get confusing when you're trying to learn about it -- for example, it's very easy to just use plain numbers and then get them mixed up with church numerals.  (I've seen this happen with many students, adapting to the kind of formal thinking that you need for this material is hard enough that throwing encodings onto the pile doesn't really help...)

As Don said, Scheme is very close to the "plain" untyped lambda calculus, and it's probably very fitting in your case if you're going through The Little Schemer.  If you really want to use a "proper" LC, you need to make sure that you use *only* functions (problems as above); but there are some additional problems that you'll run into, especially when you read various other texts on the subject.  First, most texts will use lazy evaluation which you *don't* get in Scheme.  Second, since LC has only unary functions, it's very common to shorten terms and use, for example, `λxyz.zxy` instead of the "real" form which in this case is `λx.(λy.(λz.((z x) y)))` or `(lambda (x) (lambda (y) (lambda (z) ((z x) y))))` in Scheme.  (This is called [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).)

So yes, Scheme is pretty close to LC, but that's not saying much with all of these issues.  Haskell is arguably a better candidate since it's both lazy, and does that kind of currying for multiple arguments to functions.  OTOH, you're dealing with a typed language which is a pretty big piece of baggage to bring into this game -- and you'll get in some serious mud if you try to do TLS-style examples...

If you do want to get everything (lazy, shorthands, untyped, close enough to Scheme), then [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) has another point to consider.  At a high-level, it's very close to Scheme, but it goes much farther in that you can quickly slap up a language that is a restriction of the Racket language to just `lambda` expressions and function applications.  With some more work, you can also get it to do currying and you can even make it lazy.  That's not really an exercise that you should try doing yourself at this point -- but if it sounds like what you want, then I can point you to [my course](http://pl.barzilay.org/resources.html) (look for "Schlac" in the class notes) where we use a language that is doing all of the above, and it's extremely restricted so you get nothing more than the basic LC constructs.  (For example, `3` is an unbound identifier until *you* define it.)  Note that this is not some interpreter -- it's compiled into Racket code which means that it runs fast enough that you can even write code that uses numbers.  You can get the implementation for that language there too, and once you install that, you get this language if you start files with `#lang pl schlac`.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda calculus is a very, very restricted programming model. You have only functions. No literals, no built in arithmetic operators, no data structures. Everything is encoded as functions. As such, most functional languages try to extend the lambda calculus in ways to make it more convenient for everyday programming.

Haskell uses a modern extension of lambda calculus as its core language: [System F](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), extended with data types. (GHC has since extended this further to [System Fc](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/FC), supporting type equality coercions).

As all Haskell can be written directly in its core language, and its core language is an extension of typed lambda calculus (specifically, second-order lambda calculus), it could be said that Haskell follows lambda calculus closely, modulo its builtin operators for concurrency; parallelism; and memory side effects (and the FFI). This makes development of new compiler optimizations significantly easier, and also makes the semantics of a given program more  tractable to understand.

On the other hand, Scheme is a variant of the untyped lambda calculus, extended with side effects and other non-lambda calculus concepts (such as concurrency primitives). It can be said to closely follow the untyped lambda calculus.

The only people that this matters to are: people learning the lambda calculus; and compiler writers.

Comment: Did you mean UNtyped calculus at the beginning?

Comment: Actually, untyped LC is completely unrestricted as a computation model, so you can represent everything from literals, strings, functions and all data structures and algorithms with it, it's just a potentially inconvenient form to directly deal with all that stuff in. Technically, you restrict it by adding types, but you're likely making things easier for yourself in the context of how you're defining how you're applying the semantics of your lambda calculus to practice.